# making an Arbitrary instance for a complicated type

Tags: haskell, testing, quickcheck

I'm trying to check my code using QuickCheck so I need to make `Arbitrary` instances for my types. One type `data Schedule` is complicated, and I don't know how to treat it properly. Three instances (for `Date`, `Activity`, `TimeStart`) work fine. But the last instance (for `Schedule`) is incorrect, and I seek for help with fixing it.

```
data Schedule = Schedule [(Date,[Activity])]
data Date = Date Year Month Day
data Activity = Activity (ActivityName,TimeStart)
data TimeStart = TimeStart Hour Minute

type Year = Integer
type Month = Integer
type Day = Integer
type ActivityName = String
type Hour = Integer
type Minute = Integer

instance Arbitrary Date where
  arbitrary = do
    year <- choose (2000, 2050)
    month <- choose (1, 12)
    day <- choose (1, 28)
    return $ Date year month day

instance Arbitrary Activity where
  arbitrary = do
    size <- choose (5, 15 :: Integer)
    activityName <- sequence [elements ['a'..'z'] | _ <- [1..size]]
    timeStart <- arbitrary
    return $ Activity (activityName, timeStart)

instance Arbitrary TimeStart where
  arbitrary = do
    hour <- choose (1, 24)
    minute <- choose (1, 60)
    return $ TimeStart hour minute

instance Arbitrary Schedule where
  arbitrary = do
    size <- choose (5, 50 :: Integer)
    schedule <- sequence [(arbitrary, arbitraryActivity) | _ <- [1..size]]
    return $ Schedule schedule where
      arbitraryActivity = do
        size <- choose (5, 50 :: Integer)
        activityName <- sequence [arbitrary | _ <- [1..size]]
        return $ ActivityName activityname
```

First error is in this line: `schedule <- sequence [(arbitrary, arbitraryActivity) | _ <- [1..size]]`
`Expected type: Gen [Gen b0] Actual type: (Gen a0, [Gen b0])` But how to make an arbitrary for such a construction `[(x,y)]` properly?

Second error is in the last line: `return $ ActivityName activityname`
`Data constructor not in scope: ActivityName` Is it not allowed to use `where` in do-notation the way I did?

Comment: Note that it's highly recommended to always also define `shrink` in addition to `arbitrary`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you already have `Arbitrary` instances for all the constituent types of a complex type (in this case `Date`, `Activity`, etc.), you don't have to do much.

Due to built-in `Arbitrary` instances of lists, tuples, etc., you can simply define the composed `Arbitrary` instance like this:

```
instance Arbitrary Schedule where
  arbitrary = Schedule <$> arbitrary
```

The compiler looks at the `Schedule` data constructor, which has the type `[(Date, [Activity])] -> Schedule`. It infers, then, that the right-hand `arbitrary` must have the type `Gen (Date, [Activity])`, i.e. a tuple. Does an `Arbitrary` instance exist for `(a, b)`?

Yes, it does: `(Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (a, b)`. It exists if `a` is an `Arbitrary` instance, and if `b` is.

In this case, `a ~ Date`, and you've defined a custom instance for that. The second tuple element is a bit more complex because it's `b ~ [Activity]`. Is there an `Arbitrary` instance for `[Activity]`?

Yes, again built-in: `Arbitrary a => Arbitrary [a]`. Lists have `Arbitrary` instances if the element type has an instance, and again, a custom instance exists for `Activity`.

---

It looks as though you're explicitly trying to constrain the sizes of generated values. Instead of doing this explicitly, you can use the [resize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:resize) function.